# function from script not defined

Tags: javascript, frontend, cdn

i have a problem, im using the cdn from nft.storage and web3 js. I get both get request response 200, it works when i check in network tab in console, web3 functions works, but for whatever reason when im trying to use storeMetadata() function i always get this in

```
console:Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: NFTStorage is not defined
```

Code:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nft.storage/dist/bundle.esm.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

<script>

    async function storeMetadata()
    {
        const API_KEY = process.env.NFT_STORAGE_API_KEY;
        const client = new NFTStorage({ token: API_KEY });
        const name = document.getElementById('inputName').value;
        
        const image = await convertToBlob();

         const nftProperties =
         {
            image, // use image Blob as `image` field
            name: name,
            description: "The metaverse is here. Where is it all being stored?",
            properties: 
            {
            type: "blog-post",
            origins: 
                {
                    http: "https://blog.nft.storage/posts/2021-11-30-hello-world-nft-storage/",
                    ipfs: "ipfs://bafybeieh4gpvatp32iqaacs6xqxqitla4drrkyyzq6dshqqsilkk3fqmti/blog/post/2021-11-30-hello-world-nft-storage/"
                    
                },
                authors: [{ name: "David Choi" }],
                content: 
                {
                        "text/markdown": "The last year has witnessed the explosion of NFTs onto the world’s mainstage. From fine art to collectibles to music and media, NFTs are quickly demonstrating just how quickly grassroots Web3 communities can grow, and perhaps how much closer we are to mass adoption than we may have previously thought. <... remaining content omitted ...>"
                }
            }
        }
        const metadata = await client.store(nftProperties)

          console.log('NFT data stored!')
          console.log('Metadata URI: ', metadata.url)
        return metadata.url;
    
    } //rest of my functions
```

I checked the api key and its 100% valid. Im doing this on asp net core in visual studio.

Comment: Why would the key matter if the function isn't defined? Check the Sources tab and make sure that `bundle.esm.min.js` was loaded properly.

Comment: Given the filename contains _"esm"_, I'd say you're either using the wrong file for use in a plain `<script>` tag or you need to actually use it as an ESM (aka `type="module"`)

Comment: Hey @Phil, what i wanted to do here is that i used scripts from here https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/nft.storage   and i used the type of url: "Default", not the "ESM". But i see that although the links change, both have esm in the name. I used my logic for: https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/web3 and it works. Is my logic wrong or is there maybe a problem made by this script creators that they provide wrong link?

Comment: The behaviour of one script file has no bearing on another. What does the documentation say (not the JSDeliver docs, the actual docs for NFTStorage)?

Comment: They even provide [examples](https://github.com/nftstorage/nft.storage/tree/main/examples/client/browser). I suggest you do some more reading before going in blind